# How to convert this router route?

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, iron-router

In my IronRouter.js file  I have a route to the home defined like this:

```
  Router.route('/', {
      name: 'home',
      waitOn: function() {
        return [
          Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
          Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
          Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
        ];
      },
      fastRender: true,
    });
```

Then I want to convert it into this kind of definition but the `waitOn`isn't working and creates an error :

```
Router.route('/', function(){
  this.layout('layout');
  this.render('home');
  this.next();
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  };
  fastRender: true;
});
```

So how can I convert it into the 2nd definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put waitOn property inside of function declaration, which is just wrong javascript syntax, convert it to this way:

```
Router.route('/', {
  fastRender: true,
  subscriptions: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  },
  action: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.layout('layout');
      this.render('home');
    }
  }
});
```

Iron router guide: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the subscribe aren't working like this, can you help me ?

Comment: @Jerome i've just made a change to code, you missed a check for `this.ready()`, also `this.next()` should only be called when you want the request to be processed by next matching router

Comment: @Jerome this guide should show you a lot of examples to start http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/